# Friends list nickname editing limit (~20/day?)

Tags: pokemon-go

This is probably not very interesting, but I was just classifying friends in PoGo (tagging with region and gift activity). Got following message whilst **changing friend nicknames**:

> »You've changed nicknames as many times as you can for now.«
>
> [image: warning/error message]

So presumably there's a daily limit on that. And haven't seen this particular constraint documented anywhere.

- Now I seee **17** friends with nicknames (just started).
- While 17 is the best of all prime numbers of course; it would be a strange limit here.
- Let's assume ~**20**, since I likely edited a few more than once.

Anyway, this will likely answer itself by tomorrow. But is the assumed ~20 friend nickname changes (or edits?) the **cap per day**?

Comment: I also encountered this today (I don't know exactly how many I changed), but the real question is: WHY is there a limit on this? I see no logical reason for this....

Answer (score 9):

So after some testing, my conclusion is that it's not a daily cap.

- You can have **20** friend nickname edits every **2 hours**.
- It's really *every* edit and not just effective changes. (Every save counts.)

Comment: Your graph begs the question, is it a hard or rolling window of two hours?

Comment: It's 2 hours in a rolling window. (The graph and labeling was decorative at best.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I have tried and tested is 20 friend nickname changes per hour. It has worked consistently each time by starting 5 minutes after the hour and finishing by 15 minutes until the next hour.  Sometimes you can end closer to the hour there were times that I finished by 5 minutes until the hour and it would allow me to change the next 20 a minute or two past the hour, and other times it made me wait until the next hour.  it is all about timing, your time versus the game time.  I have noticed that Ex-Raid times are off which has to do with server time deviation.

Comment: Your experience might support the conclusion that it's a rolling window.